# How to express a large number as a formula of smaller numbers

Tags: math, biginteger

I need to represent very large numbers (on the order of 8 kB or more) using a mathematical expression consisting of smaller numbers. One form of this would be factoring, as in `81 = 9 * 9`. But for some numbers, factoring would not work. In that case, a more complex expression would be required.

For example, the number `78125` can be represented by two smaller numbers `78125 = 5 ^ 7`. But `78121` can not be factored. So the expression would be `78121 = 5 ^ 7 - 4`. For the number sizes I'm interested in, the expression might be something like `n = (511 ^ 213) * (327 ^ 400)`

What type of algorithm would allow me calculate these types of short-cut expressions?

(Edited to try to make it more clear)

Comment: You seem to have a loose definition of "factoring". What is that factorization example you provided called? What is that form, exactly?

Comment: That's not an equation. (An equation is a proposition of the form `a = b` where `a` and `b` can be any expressions.)

Comment: @DonkeyKong Factoring is probably the wrong term. Like I said, the example was just something a fed into bc to let people know the kind of thing I'm looking for. It could be factors, or any equation that uses relatively small numbers (like 16 or 32 bit) to represent the larger number.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand ok, edited to include an equal sign.

Comment: Terms often thrown around for this are  "Kolgomorov complexity" and "System entropy".

Comment: Voting to closed; If "factoring" is the wrong term, you need to define precisely what you do mean,  What characterizes the result you provided?  I'll retract my close vote if you can be more specific.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're asking. It would take milliseconds to factor the number in your example. EDIT: Oh, my bad, I see you are adding a term .

Comment: @andand I edited the question trying to make it more clear. If I knew what to call it, I could probably Google it and wouldn't need to post the question.

Comment: @JohnFrickson Your explanation is still vague.  For instance, you could just let `m=floor(sqrt(n))`, then `n = m^2 + diff`, where `diff` is just what needs to be added to `m^2` to get `n`.

Comment: You could use some kind of basis representation. E.g. `123,456 = 12 * 10^4 + 34 * 10^2 + 56`.

Comment: No, don't close it. It is perfectly clear what he wants: Is there an algorithm or small set of algorithms to make any number be expressed in a simple expression, consisting of simple operations like +, -, * and to-the-power-of on 32 bit or 64 bit numbers at most. He gives a few examples as well. If this were possible, this could be an extremely powerful way to compress data, so I guess it is not (without precision loss).